# Homeomorphic map that doesn't imply smoothness

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

> Let $S= \{x\in \mathbf{R^3} \mid x_3 = \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2} \}.$ Construct a $C^1$ homeomorphism $\varphi : \mathbf{R^2} \to S.$ Explain why the constructed homeomorfism doesn't imply that $S$ is smooth?

So I would need to construct a map $\varphi : \mathbf{R^2} \to S$ that is a continuous bijection whose inverse is also continuous.

If I let $\varphi(x_1,x_2) =(x_1,x_2, \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2})$ which is essentially a parametrization for the graph of $S$ right? Is this map a homeomorphism?

If I would have constructed $\varphi(x_1,x_2)=(x_1^3,x_2^3, \sqrt{x_1^6+x_2^6})$ this would at least be homeomorphic since $x \mapsto x^3$ is homeomorphic.

Now I would be left to show that $\varphi$ is a $C^1$ that is, it has continuous partials, which isn't that hard to show, however how can I show that this doesn't imply that $S$ is smooth?

Comment: What is your definition of smooth? Embedded submanifold?

Comment: This was asked in an Analysis II class so $S$ would be smooth if I have that $f : U \to \mathbf{R}^{n-m}$ and rank$(D\varphi) = n-m$. @Caffeine